# Can't install imblearn to use SMOTE in my Mac

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, package, imblearn

I have a Mac Book and I've been struggling to install imblearn. I tried running "conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn" in the anaconda terminal but whenever I run my functions in my Jupyter notebook I get an error as if I never installed the package. This has happened with other packages before and I never figured out why this happens. Is there a different way of doing this with Macs?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the logs that contain the errors.

Comment: When I run:

import imblearn
imblearn.__version__

it returns:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-31138131cac9> in <module>
----> 1 import imblearn
      2 imblearn.__version__

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `virtual environment` to isolate packages and avoid conflict. Then you can add a virtual environment to your jupyter notebook. Here's how:

Create a virtual env:

```
python3 -m venv your_env_name
```

Activate environment:

```
source your_evn_name/bin/activate
```

Install environment packages e.g.:

```
pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

Install ipykernel:

```
pip install ipykernel
```

In the active environment, Install the new kernel

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=your_kernel_name
```

Then lunch jupyter notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

Within notebooks, select the kernel you created (ie. `your_kernel_name`) to start a new notebook with your environment settings.